# Sectioned PHP website like Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, web

I am working on a PHP website, and don't want to have to write headers, footers, etc. for every page. I came up with the idea to have written headers and footers that could be retrieved with a function just like Wordpress. I found Wordpress's `get_header();` function in `/wp-includes/general-template.php` but it loads through a template which I do not have being a hand written website. My question is "How do I write multiple PHP files such as header.php, and footer.php, etc. and compile them in to one document in the index.php?

Comment: Look into PHP includes. http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look into the [**`include()`**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php) function, along with the similar `include_once()`, `require()`, and `require_once()`.

Comment: When the `include('header.php');` is added, the content of index.php no longer shows, nor does footer info.

Comment: It sounds like you are not either not supplying the right path to the header file or the file has an error in it.  Check your php error logs.

Answer (score 0):

A. Make sure your index page is index.php and not index.html.
B. Write one header file, header.php, and use if/else statements to bring in the content you want for that particular page.
C. Use `<?php include('header.php'); ?>`at the top of your index.php and `<?php include('footer.php'); ?>` at the bottom of your page.
D. If this isn't working, make sure your server has PHP installed on it.